# Animation Logic

Tags: animation, logic-bricks

I wanted to create a clock concept in Blender yet I want for it to have a working animation for it too. Now I could use physics for the gears but that's too much hassle with the collision mesh and what not. So I was wondering if I could logic to the animation. Like if I rotate the hour gear it will move the minute gear x number of degrees. Sorry if I have bad English.

Comment: You mean you want to **rig** a clock mechanism? I'd suggest using constraints.

Comment: From the logic editor? Check this model from Blendswap: http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/71021 . It uses Python script & Game Logic.